# In Corda, how to upgrade a state without needing to change its name?

Tags: corda

I have a state RegisteredV1 with some attributes and I want to add few variables to this state but want to keep its name as RegisteredV1.
As of now I see that the new contract that will be upgrading the state will have to have both states imported and that can be one reason why keeping the name same might not be possible, but is there any work around for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi this is not the case when you use Corda 4 and above with Signature constraint. You can keep the same state name. To perform an upgrade, simply stop the node, replace old jar with new jar, start the node. The additional parameters should get added to the table in the database.